# Fitting data to a line, where the data itself has tolerances

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, fitting

I need to fit data to a line.
This data also includes tolerances.

**Now, I was wondering, if there exists a method, to account for those tolerances?**

For instance, a data point with a lot of tolerances should not be given the same weight as a data point with small tolerances.

Here is a sample of my data:

$$
\begin{array}{c|r|r}
x & \text{data point }(y) & \pm\text{ standard deviation} \\
\hline
1 & 120.984 & 0.426248 \\
2 & 132.194 & 0.418291 \\
3 & 130.413 & 1.260100 \\
4 & 127.687 & 0.414457 \\
5 & 125.710 & 0.410716 \\
6 & 128.188 & 1.431200
\end{array}
$$

I was maybe thinking of applying weighted least squares, but I don't know how to implement it. 
Is this the best solution ?

Comment: What is the tolerance please, that is, is it 5%, like a 95% confidence interval, or something else?

Comment: @Carl, the tolerances are actually measurement error. -> a range in which the true value can be.

Comment: Within a certain tolerance. Name the tolerance, please. Common electrical component tolerances are for example 1%, 5%, 10%, and 20%. And, specify what it comes from as there are alternative measures that are called tolerances depending on [method of calculation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance)

Comment: @whuber : ok, I'll go through the details and see if you're right and maybe then edit this answer and restore it. Or maybe not...... (It seems I cannot comment on a deleted answer. They ought to change that.)

Comment: @Carl I checked the data, and it is std. deviation

Comment: In which case it should be listed as $\pm1 SD$.

Comment: Is the measurement error on X or Y?

Comment: @DoHe : Is it a standard deviation estimated based on the data, or is it precisely known independently of the data?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I think, that it is based on the data.

Answer (score 1):

Weighted least squares with weights proportional to the reciprocal of the square of the tolerance would give the best unbiased estimates if the tolerances were the standard deviations of measurement errors.

Comment: I don't believe this would be the case: otherwise, the weights neglect an appreciable variance component coming from the residuals.

Comment: @whuber : Recent comments under the question suggest that the "tolerances" are just standard deviations of the errors. (Whether they are estimated or known wasn't specified last I checked. If they are known up to a constant factor, then I think my answer is right. If they are estimated, then my answer is certainly incomplete.

Comment: Let's be careful in our use of the term "errors."  A plot of the data makes it very clear that these tolerances are unlikely to have any relationship to the regression errors: they appear to be *measurement errors.*  Thus an appropriate model would be of the form $$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+\delta_i+\epsilon_i$$ where the variance of $\delta_i$ is proportional to the squared "tolerance," the variance of $\epsilon_i$ is constant, and the $\delta_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ are independent zero-mean random variables. To justify using $1/\text{tolerance}^2$ as weights, you need to ignore the $\epsilon_i$.

Comment: @whuber : So then $\operatorname{var}(\delta_i+\varepsilon_i) = \sigma^2 + (\text{tolerance}_i)^2,$ and that weights should be proportional to the reciprocals of those, and $\sigma^2$ needs to be estimated somehow.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue.